# jquery .valid() validating all offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I'm having a strange problem with jquery's .valid() function on submit.  Jquery naturally calls this on a from submit, but I've extracted the exact function call of jquery causing the problem below

```
$("#validateMe").click(function () {
    alert($("form").valid());
});
```

The reason it's a problem is because it keeps calling offset width/offset height for every input, including my checkboxes.

The checkboxes are generated by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].Selected)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbMajor)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbHeading)
        <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].Selected, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-pbmajor", Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbMajor }, { "data-pbheading", Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbHeading } })
        @Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbMajor
        @Model.CategoryViewModel.ChildCategoryNodes[i].PbHeading
        </label>
    }
}
```

Each individual input in the form the offsetWidth and offsetHeight get's checked. Usually this doesn't matter if form is very small, but I have < 2000 check-boxes being loaded onto the page.  There are so many though it's given an overall slow user experience on page time.

[image: Bad Loading Time]

Any answers for a work-around or fix of my code for this would be helpful!

Comment: Is validating on the server instead of the client an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is known to slow down with really large forms. See [jQuery validate large forms - script running slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5542014/3191599) and [Long form using jquery Validate causes IE slow script warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999374/long-form-using-jquery-validate-causes-ie-slow-script-warning).

You have a couple of options. I'd approach them in this order:

- Customize or override jQuery's default validation function. The above 2 answers give some example of that, as well as this one: [Custom method with jQuery Validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589152/custom-method-with-jquery-validation-plugin)
- Paginate the form. Do you really need ~2000 checkboxes on a single form? Is there a way to split it up into multiple pages?
- Validate on the server side. If your application logic supports it, allow the form to be submitted even if invalid, run your validation logic on the server side, and then return the page with any validation messages if necessary.

Comment: I think I might try a mix of these.  I really do need all 2000 on the same page unfortunately (business requirement).

Comment: Any thoughts on using HTML5 input validators for this?

Comment: @Richard I don't have any experience with HTML5 input validation as I haven't had to use it before. Someone else may be able to shed some light on that.